# Total allocation of a java program

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, heap-memory, allocation

I'm trying to figure out how much memory a java program allocates and I believe that JVM does not provide an option for that.

Am I wrong?

So I'm running my program using the options

`-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps`

And so far I've used the G1GC collector and the Concurrent Mark and Sweep collector.

And for both collectors I got the following outputs:

`Heap
garbage-first heap   total 27545600K, used 1882393K ...
  region size 4096K, 289 young (1183744K), 41 survivors (167936K)
Metaspace       used 3687K, capacity 4660K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K`

and

`Heap 
par new generation   total 620544K, used 319848K ...
eden space 551616K,  52% used ...
from space 68928K,  40% used ...
to   space 68928K,   0% used ...
concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1379008K, used 44914K [0x000000015fb90000, 0x00000001b3e40000, 0x0000000800000000)
Metaspace       used 3688K, capacity 4660K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K`

I wonder if the values next to 'total' are what i'm looking for.

And if they are, what are the values next to 'use'?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The numbers next to "used" are the amounts used out of the total. To owrk out the amount allocated you can total how much has been freed plus the difference of how much is used.

However, using a memory profiler like flight recorder or VisualVM is a much easier way to analyse your memory usage and why.

Comment: So the "used" field has how many bytes were not collected in the end of the execution, that is, how much memory is still allocated. Correct?